# USB electrical output control

Tags: java, android, usb

I program with java for an android application and I wish to control the current that the USB applies.
How do I do that?

I want to turn on and off the electric current of the USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. The Android device is a USB client and not a host, thus it only receives the electric current on its USB bus and it's not able to control it. And AFAIK the USB current (voltage) is something defined by the USB standard and not modifiable.

Comment: Depends on the device if it's a USB client or host. Android devices can act as USB hosts. See [USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html) *(This doesn't neccessarily mean that the current can be controlled, I guess that is handled by the hardware on its own, but that's - well just another guess :) )*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I didn't know that. Anyway you can't change electrical properties of the bus, they're defined by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control that.

You can find the USB technical documents [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/).